# Typescript error:- Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'string'

Tags: angular, typescript

whenever i used forEach() i got this error in terminal

```
[ts] Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

My application works in browser properly. Everything works properly but i don't want such errors in terminal.

I used below code for it. Please suggest me what i missing.

```
 job.forEach(function(state) {
        if((totalcarer['userId']+"")===state.rNo)
        {
          cjobState = state.cJobstatus;
        }
      });
```

Comment: What is `job`? Where do you assign it?

Comment: it is an array.

Comment: Incomplete information. You need provide all the relevant information to the question and bug.

Comment: Its not an `array`. your `job` is a `string` That is what error is trying to say.

Comment: If the error message says it's a `string` it probably is a `string`.

Comment: `*ngFor()` why you are not opted this?

Comment: look i used  var job=jobs['sentCarer'];

Comment: What is `jobs` ?

Comment: @jai i am in .ts file so i used forEach()

Comment: @harishmahajan You cant provide one by one information. It gets too dragy. Can you provide everything inorder for us to re-create the bug?

Comment: @harishmahajan `var job=jobs['sentCarer'] ` how can you say job is an array. it might be a string also.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
arrays: string[];
arrayString: string;
```

See the diff between? one is array and another is string.

```
arrays.forEach(...) // valid.
arrayString.forEach(...) //invalid.
```

Comment: What is `jobs` ?

Comment: it is an array variable. 
thanks. now i used  public job:String; and works

Comment: Then what does `['sentCarer']` do?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that TypeScript is trying to save you from accidentially calling forEach on keys when it's a string type, as it could fail on runtime. You will need to make sure keys are type of array before calling foreach:

```
if (Array.isArray(job)) {
  job.forEach(...);
}
```